# Core graphics paths drawing V.S. Image layers blending: which is more performance costly?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I implemented a UICollectionView that contains many blocks as shown below.
And each of the block is drawn with Core Graphics using paths.

I am wondering, for each of the small blocks, instead of drawing its shapes with paths, but using two layers of static images, one as background (opaque), the other as foreground (partially-transparent), to blend into the same drawing. Will the performance be significantly improved?

I am asking because right now the perf is really bad using core graphics, and I used the xCode profiler to trace the perf cost, all the heavy lifting are in these path drawings.

Any ideas? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Storing the paths into images would def be better performance. Can the colllectionview be scrolled?  The collection view may be the cause of lots of rerenders

Comment: Also CAShapeLayer may be more performant than drawRect. Not really sure how you are doing it

Comment: Yeah, if your collection view isn't scrollable, you should probably just create the tiles views and lay them out directly. But if you want the absolute best performance, you need to draw the canvas using Metal. You could do the entire thing in a single draw call.

Comment: @agibson007, yes the collection view is scrollable. I have a gallery page that contains many of these uploaded art from users, looks similar to instagram.

Comment: @robmayoff Yes, I will check out the Metal, first time heard of it. But it looks very promising. Thanks. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal

Comment: CATiledLayer would be what I would experiment with first to not have to deal with the overhead of metal. Also if you go down the metal route you could potentially use SpriteKit to avoid the overhead. An example collectionnode might be something like this. https://github.com/bwide/CollectionNode/blob/master/Source/CollectionNode.swift